# 2D Array suddenly becomes undefined while iterating in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a global 2D Array and iterate through the values like so (MAXV = 100, defined in graph.h):

```
#include "graph.h"

int adjacency_array[MAXV][MAXV];

manipulate(graph *g){
    int m,n;
    for (m = 1; m <= g->nvertices; m++){
        for (n = 1; n <= g->nvertices; n++){
            if (m != n){
                if (adjacency_array[n][m] != 1){
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm only concerned with indexes 1-6, not 0 or >6. In this case, `g->nvertices` is 6. At one point while iterating through the 2D array, I'm getting a seg. fault at `if (adjacency_array[n][m] != 1)`. The specific case it seg. faults at is when m=4 and n=3. Checking any value of the array will seg. fault at that point, so I don't know if those values specifically are a problem. I'm sorry if what I have provided isn't clear, I'll try to clarify if needed.

Comment: Not enough info.  `adjacency_array[3][4]` is valid, given `MAXV = 100`.

Comment: The only thing I see in that code which could cause a seg fault is an invalid pointer in argument `g`.

Comment: in C, any array is referenced by 0...max-1 .  What is the value of g->nvertices?  could it be that on the 'm' itteration that the max value should be g->mvertices rather than g->nvertices?

Comment: To get good help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your assumptions (`MAXV == 100` and `g->nvertices == 6`) your code should not seg-fault, ergo your assumptions are wrong.

The most likely explanation is the pointer g you are passing is not correctly initialized, or is not a graph pointer.
In this case accessing `g->nvertices` may cause a seg fault or may return a value that is equal or greater than `MAXV` causing a seg-fault when accessing `adjacency_array[n][m]`.
[Microsoft's C Runtime for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) fills memory with large numbers when in debug mode.

Have you tried running with a debugger or printing the values of `MAXV` and `g->nvertices`?